# kafka consumer lag increases too much

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have 10 brokers and lately many of them have been getting "too many files open" errors. Then the broker dies. When we check the number of files open by the kafka process, it's usually 70k or more. On checking (lsof -p {pid}), most of the files opened by kafka are of the name "can't identify protocol". Upon restart, when we check the lag for topics, it has increased by a huge amount, say if previously it was 800 million, the it becomes 10 billion.

First question: Why is the broker opening all these files? Didn't have this issue in the past and we haven't upgraded or changed kafka version.

Second question: Why does the lag increase so much in such a short period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kafka, a topic partition maps to a log file on disk. So with the increase in number of topic/partitions, the number of files accessed by kafka would also increase. You could increase the limit on the number of files to be opened (on linux it is usually determined by ulimit).

Lag increase is expected as brokers going up and down can have potential impact on the consumers as it could trigger rebalances across consumers which would halt consumption till rebalance is complete (impact on producers is usually negligible assuming replication). As for the amount of lag, this is dependent at your producer throughput.

For instance if your producer produces 100msgs/sec, and your rebalance takes 1min, you have already accumulated a lag of 6000. A deep dive is needed in consumer logs to see why consumer gets blocked and for how long. This then needs to be mapped with producer throughput to justify the lag numbers.